# using slice() to retrieve items from the end of an array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, default-value, conditional-operator

Disclaimer: I'm new to JS.
So, all of my test are passing but one - the last one - and I can't figure out how to fix it. Why is 0 returning the last element and not an empty array? Also, on a separate note, when I tried to use a default value it returned the wrong values hence why I decided to include a conditional statement.

```
const takeRight = (array, n) => {
n = -n;
//setting both default and a negative value for 'n': if there is no number, then n should be -1
const condition = !n ? -1 : n;
return array.slice(condition);
};

console.log(takeRight([1, 2, 3])); // returns [3] --> expected [3] 
console.log(takeRight([1, 2, 3], 2)); //returns [2, 3] --> expected [2,3] 
console.log(takeRight([1, 2, 3], 5)); //returns [1, 2, 3] --> expected [1,2,3]
console.log(takeRight([1, 2, 3], 0)); //returns [3] --> expected []
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in calculating `condition` variable:

```js
const condition = !n ? -1 : n;
```

expression `!0` is true, so `n` is changed to `-1` when has value `0`.

If you want to check against not a numbers, use `isNaN`.:

```js
const takeRight = (array, n) => {
    n = isNaN(n) ? -1 : -n;
    return array.slice(n);
};
```

Comment: thank you! Man, I knew it would be a simple solution, but not this simple. Complete palm-to-face moment

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your expression. Check for "Not a Number"

```
const condition = isNaN(n) ? -1 : n;
```

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, you shouldn't reassign arguments. But the actual issue here is using `!n` to test if it exists. It might be a neat trick here and there but is actually just confusing. Prefixing anything with a `!` in JavaScript turns it into a boolean and then negates it, and the rules for this conversion are not obvious and also not the same in every language. But in JS, `!0` gives you the same result as `!undefined` or `!null`, because the number 0 often symbolizes an "off-state", basically a `false`, but shorter. Anyways, to avoid all of that, just use default parameters and use a ternary operator in the return statement to check for the specific case of `n = 0` like so:

```js
const takeRight = (array, n = 1) => n === 0 ? [] : condition array.slice(-n);
```

You can of course make that a bit more verbose as well:

```js
const takeRight = (array, n = 1) => {
    if (n === 0) {
        return [];
    }

    return condition array.slice(-n);
};
```

EDIT: Even `!""` returns `true` by the way, which is not really "obvious" as well, so using `!` to check if something is defined or exists, can really cause problems and unexpected outcomes. I'd advise against it unless you really really know what you are doing and why.

Comment: "first of all, you shouldn't reassign arguments"
Thank you for this! I've been told this before, so it's good to hear it again - so that sinks in and I can be more aware of and strategic with the code I use(i.e. self monitor), and not simply use code I'm comfortable with.